# Maneuvering the ball effectively while in a corner

Tags: rocket-league

I'm starting to get the hang of this game but I'm having a bit of trouble when the ball ends up in one of the rounded corners on either side of the opponents goal.  Often the ball gets struck and simply ends in a slow, high arc in the air.  Is there a recommended approach or strategy to control the ball and get it moving toward the goal instead of the typical smash-fest that keeps it in the corner and rolling up the wall?

Comment: I won't answer with this because I wouldn't say this is the *best* for everyone... But when it's heading into a corner, I try to get toward the outside and hit it at an angle that allows it to roll around the corner instead of up. With any luck it can roll right in front of the goal (and hopefully a teammate is ready for it and the typical smash-fest doesn't happen)

Comment: I suspect all answers to this will be very subjective, but anyway. You can do what _DangerZone_ said, or you can do the opposite and try to hit it so it bounces off the side wall and ends up center field. I find that any experienced defender will rarely let a corner-rolling ball slip past them. Just make sure your teammates are ready to strike, or their goalie may clear it (and since he has a clear shot of your goal... *shudders*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After watching pros such as Kronovi play 1v1 matches (or even 3v3/4v4), I have to say one of the best strategies for getting the ball off of the corner wall is this:

- Drive up the wall and position yourself as close to the ball as possible
- Jump and flip (sideways or backward depending on your angle) to hit the ball **up** and away from the wall
- Attempt to get the ball to hit the ceiling so it falls down faster
- If you have boost, jump again and fly at the ball to push it toward the goal

It's a very tricky tactic, but if you can pull it off, it catches your opponent(s) off guard 80% of the time.